# A cipher was found within this video, what method would be used to solve it?

Tags: cipher

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TebCHHCw9rY&feature=youtu.be), at 22:53, there is a cipher, and I haven't the slightest idea how to solve it.

[image: cipher]

In plaintext:

> OPIJOIJ MNOIM MO:AMWDOAM wth SO HELP ME GOD

It doesn't seem to be random gibberish, but I have no idea what method was used to create it and in turn no idea how to decipher it.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution to puzzle. but I found it interesting enough to post.

> Considering Text to be OPIJOIJ MNOIMMO : AMWDOAM

I did a ROT-12 that translates to this :

> ABUVAUV YZAUYYA : MYIPAMY

That gave me nothing. But I considered it one word rather than three to make it :

> ABUVAUVYZAUYYA : MYIPAMY

Then, If we translate the word before colons, Google Translate [for ALL LETTERS in CAPS](https://translate.google.com/#sn/en/ABUVAUVYZAUYYA) shows this :

> DIRECTORS

and [for ALL LETTERS in UNDERCAPS](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/abuvauvyzauyya) shows this :

> in the future

So, Google translate shows both of them to be `shona` language and I'll go with what undercaps shows. Though I cannot relate it with video in any way. Sorry about that.